# Select from a single grid only - multiple ng-grids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have a requirement where there are two grids and I want to limit the user from selecting for a single grid only (and only a single row) at any point of time.

```
/**
        * function generates data mart schedule grid option
        * 
        * @public
        * @returns (object) grid options
        **/
        systemReportsConfigOptions: function () {
            return {
                data: "systemReports",
                editable: false,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                multiSelect: false,
                columnDefs: [{
                    field: "reportName",
                    displayName: "System Reports",
                    //width: 'auto',
                    cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="onSystemReportsGridSelect()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>'
                }],
                height: '100',
                keepLastSelected: false
            };
        },
        /**
        * function generates report config grid option
        * 
        * @public
        * @returns (object) grid options
        **/
        userReportsConfigOptions: function ()
        {
            return {
                data: "userReports",
                editable: false,
                enableSorting: false,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                multiSelect: false,
                columnDefs: [{
                    field: "reportName",
                    displayName: "User-Defined Reports",
                    //width: 'auto',
                    cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="onUserReportsGridSelect()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>'
                }],
                height: '100',
                keepLastSelected: false
            };
        },
```

Here is my grid selection handling code:

```
/**
   * function at selecting System Reports grid
   * 
   * @private
   **/
    function onSystemReportsGridSelect() {
        //debugger;
        $scope.userReportsConfigOptions.selectAll(false);

        $scope.selectedReport = { reportId: this.row.entity.reportId, reportName: this.row.entity.reportName };

        $scope.deleteButtonDisabled = false;
    };

    /**
   * function at selecting User-Defined Reports grid
   * 
   * @private
   **/
    function onUserReportsGridSelect() {
        //debugger;
        $scope.systemReportsConfigOptions.selectAll(false);

        $scope.selectedReport = { reportId: this.row.entity.reportId, reportName: this.row.entity.reportName };

        $scope.deleteButtonDisabled = false;
    };
```

The selection works in a very inconsistent manner. Some times it allows rows from both grids to be selected. But when I dig in, it shows the previous selection only and not the current one.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what kind of *inconsistent manner* ?

Comment: It allows selection from both the grids at times. But stores only the previous selection and not the current. I want the user be able to select a single row from only one of the grid at any point of time. And store the latest selection!